# Oracle-update multiple row value where the the id column equals specific values

Tags: oracle

I am new in oracle and I want to update multiple row value where the column `id = 1 , 2`.

I tried this :

```
update Tester 
set employee_phone_number = ( 0789456123,0789456321)  
where employee_id in (1,2);
```

but it gives me "missing right parenthesis"

any help please and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the intention to set `employee_phone_number` to "0789456123" for the row where `id = 1` and to "0789456321" for the row where `id = 2`?  Is `employee_phone_number` a `NUMBER`?  Or a `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: Are you storing phone numbers as numbers or as character strings? Storing them as numbers would seem to be a mistake as you lose the "0" prefix.

Comment: set employee_phone_number to "0789456123" for the row where id = 1 and to "0789456321" for the row where id = 2 and the employee_phone_number is NUMBER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach:

```
merge into
  tester
using (
  select 1 id,'0123456785' employee_phone_number from dual union all
  select 2 id,'0123456786' employee_phone_number from dual) new_values
on (
  tester.id = new_values.id)
when matched then update 
  set employee_phone_number = new_values.employee_phone_number;
```

More words, but allows the values to be specified in only one place and extends to allow inserts where the id does not already exist.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fc86/3

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
update Tester 
set employee_phone_number = CASE WHEN employee_id = 1 THEN 0789456123
                                 WHEN employee_id = 2 THEN 0789456321
                            END
where employee_id in (1,2);
```